# Seaborn pairplot() error, OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'mode.use_inf_as_null'", any idea?

Tags: python, seaborn, inf, pairplot

I am thrown an error when I am trying to apply searbor pairplot.
My full script is easy, and is copied as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': np.random.randn(100),
    'B': np.random.randn(100),
    'C': np.random.randn(100),
    'D': np.random.randn(100)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a pair plot
sns.pairplot(df)
```

But I am thrown this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OptionError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 15
     12 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
     14 # Create a pair plot
---> 15 sns.pairplot(df)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/marketing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py:46, in _deprecate_positional_args..inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     36     warnings.warn(
     37         "Pass the following variable{} as {}keyword arg{}: {}. "
     38         "From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument "
   (...)
     43         FutureWarning
     44     )
     45 kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46 return f(**kwargs)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/marketing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py:2126, in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind, diag_kind, markers, height, aspect, corner, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws, grid_kws, size)
   2124 diag_kws.setdefault("legend", False)
   2125 if diag_kind == "hist":
-> 2126     grid.map_diag(histplot, **diag_kws)
   2127 elif diag_kind == "kde":
   2128     diag_kws.setdefault("fill", True)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/marketing/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py:1478, in PairGrid.map_diag(self, func, **kwargs)
...
--> 121     raise OptionError(f"No such keys(s): {repr(pat)}")
    122 if len(keys) > 1:
    123     raise OptionError("Pattern matched multiple keys")

OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'mode.use_inf_as_null'"
```

I have tried removing Seaborn, and reinstalled again with the conda command, but the error is the same.

Have anyone encountered this error before?

Comment: What is your seaborn version (`print(sns.__version__)`)? If I run your code with v0.12.2, I don't see any error.

Comment: thank you for dropping by! it was v 0.11.2, I used `conda remove`, then `conda install`. But the old version 0.11.2 was so sturdy and stayed no matter what. I then tried `conda install seaborn=v0.12.2`, and `=v0.12'` but both gave me an error `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels`. I am guessing maybe because mine is a M1 Mac?

Comment: Just try `conda install -c conda-forge seaborn=0.12.2`. I've tried on an M1 Mac and that seems to work for me.

Comment: Current channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

Comment: Are you saying it still doesn't install with the above command? If so, I'm not sure why.

Comment: You're using `miniforge3` as opposed to a full version of anaconda, so maybe something go updated and caused a conflict. I'd try `conda update --all`. Optionally, create a new environment as shown in https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge seaborn=0.12.2` solved my problem! conda-forge channel does the magic.

Comment: @MattPitkin could you write your comment as an answer? I was getting the same error but updated from v0.12.0 to v0.12.2 and everything was solved. I think that's the best answer we're going to get.

Answer (score 8):

Just do the following:

```bash
pip install --upgrade seaborn
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to just be an issue with a particular seaborn version that is solved by using seaborn v0.12.2 or above. This can be installed in a conda environment with, e.g.,:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge seaborn=0.12.2
```

Comment: I tried upgrading seaborn and it didn't help. I had to uninstall pandas too like @Jakhon suggested.

Answer (score 3):

It is due to `pandas`. For some reason, `pandas` and `seaborn` are not getting well. If you uninstall both `pandas` and `seaborn` and install only `seaborn`,  the `seaborn` will automatically install the right `pandas` it works well with. Thus, your error will go away. At least, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be specific to your environment or code setup. To troubleshoot further, please consider the following steps:

```
pip uninstall seaborn matplotlib
pip install seaborn matplotlib
```

I had issues with the following code:

```
 sns.distplot(df_benign['mean area'], 
         bins=5, 
         ax=ax[0], 
         label='Benign',
         hist_kws={"hatch": "x"})
```

I did those step and it worked for me.